# Check if datagridview value is not null when changing cell

Tags: c#

I'm using a `CellEndEdit` Event for capturing currentCell Value when I'm leaving from it. The problem is that, if the user deletes all the cell and trying to move to another cell I'm getting error `Exception thrown System.NullReference`.

Here is my code which I tell that if the cell is null or empty do nothing

I tried:

```
 if ( AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != "")
 if ( AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
 if ( AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() != "")
 if ( AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() != "")
 if ( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
```

Nothing from above doesn't work I get the `Null reference`.
Is there any other to check if my current cell doesn't have something inside?

Comment: On which exact line you get the exception?

Comment: The line after if statement, which means that avoids my exceptions

Comment: Still not clear. There are 5 `if`s in your question, can you share the code that executes after all these statements?

Comment: Please edit your answer to indicate which line raises the exception and remove the others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `Value` is null. You can use the null propagation operator `?` to avoid the exception.

```
 if ( AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]?.Value != "")
 if ( AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]?.Value != null)
 if ( AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]?.Value.ToString() != "")
 if ( AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]?.Value.ToString() != "")
 if ( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AppointmentGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]?.Value.ToString()))
```

Comment: @Dim this *is* an example ^